# Java addRequestProperty for soap 1.2 Content-Type action

Tags: java, soap-client

Is this right declaration? I am not sure about action property.

HttpsURLConnection connection = this.getConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action= http://someaddress_execute");